# Type for an object that starts empty, but then has properties added

Tags: typescript, types, type-conversion

Currently in my code I declare an empty object:

`const coverageProps = {}`

and then loop over some other data and add properties to the object. I want to provide a type for the `coverageProps` variable, but am running into some errors. This is currently how I'm attempting to type it:

```
type CoveragePropKeys = 'cut' | 'support' | 'coverage';
const coverageProps: Record<CoveragePropKeys, string> = {};
```

But, this gives me a TypeScript error because the object is initially empty, and is doesn't have keys for cut, support, and coverage (from `CoveragePropTypes`). This is the exact error from TS:
`Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Record<CoveragePropKeys, string>': "cut", "support", "coverage"`

I know I can change the type to a union like the following:

```
const coverageProps: Record<CoveragePropKeys, string> | object = {};
```

but then later in my code where I'm adding properties, I get another TS error due to the fact that `coverage props` essentially has the any type and strings can't be used to index type {}. I could address this error, but I just don't want to go this route because I'm losing type checking.

I'm fairly new to TypeScript and still learning best practices. What is a proper way to handle this situation?

Comment: Can you show a [mcve] that demonstrates how you are looping and setting properties?  My guess is that you will have to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) like `const coverageProps = {} as Record<CoveragePropKeys, string>` and then make very sure you add all the required properties before you do anything else, since you've technically lied to the compiler until the object is initialized.  There is no real convenient and completely type safe solution to this as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `?` optional operator and declare the type that you want

```
type CoveragePropKeys = {cut?: string; support?: string; coverage?: string};
const coverageProps: CoveragePropKeys = {};

coverageProps.cut = 'some value'; //allowed
coverageProps.support = 5; //error property must be string or undefined
```