# Typing for progressively adding properties to an object

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-types

I have a situation that I run into fairly often:
I have an object that properties are added to progressively as values are computed.

For example (based on actual code):

```js
declare const getString: () => string;
declare const map: Map<string, unknown>

type Thing = {
  foo: string;
};

const thing: Thing = {} // Error: Property 'foo' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Thing'.

const string = getString() // Assume this is really expensive or can only be run once.
if (map.has(string)) thing.foo = string
else thing.foo = "blank"
```

There are more properties, of course.

The issue here is that the properties must be non-optional, but I can't create the object with them.
I do, of course, want the object to still be typed in some way, so that invalid assignments are prevented.

How can I type this?

---

My first attempt was to create the object with `Partial` and then check it using either the function return type (if it is being returned from a function) or a variable assignment.

For example:

```js
// Function return type
function createThing(): Thing {
  const thing: Partial<Thing> = {}
  // ...
  return thing
}

// Variable assignment
const thing: Partial<Thing> = {}
// ...
const thing2: Thing = thing
```

However, these checks always fail as `thing` is never narrowed and so is still considered to be `Partial<Thing>`.

Taking inspiration from ["Dynamically adding properties to objects and return new type with the properties"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74021566/15261914), I tried using a function to do the assignment, but without success:

```js
const addProp = <T extends object, K extends keyof Thing, V>(
  obj: T,
  key: K,
  value: V
): T & Record<K, V> => Object.assign(obj, { [key]: value } as Record<K, V>);

thing = addProp(thing, "foo", "blank");
```

The `addProp` function returns the correct type, but the type of `thing` is not changed.

Of course, this would require you to reassign the variable every time, too.

In similar spirit to the above, I tried doing the assignment in a type assertion function, but those require all generic type parameters to be specified.

---

Note: I am aware of ["Type for an object that starts empty, but then has properties added"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67506839/15261914), but it is two years old; I do not know if trying to revive it would be any good. @jcalz said there that "there is no real convenient and completely type safe solution to this as far as [he knows]", but I hope that something has been added or changed that allows it, or that someone has discovered a way. I have also added my own attempts and findings, which I feel justifies posting a new question.

Comment: `const thing = { foo: map.get(getString()) ?? 'blank' };` and repeat for all the other properties. What am I missing here? I basically never ever need to build up and object the way you're describing unless I'm converting a JS file that was written that way.

Comment: The thing here is that it is simply checking if the Map _has_ the key. It does not use the value in the map. In my code, this is a check if a related object is in a cache of sorts. The fetched value needs to be used twice, so I used a temp var instead of recalculating it. I was trying to be minimal, but I can update it with expanded code?

Comment: You could make `addProp()` an [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) and use it like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w8Xqrw), does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks, that works! Seems that the issue I had when trying it myself was that I used an arrow function, not a function declaration. Here's what I'll probably end up using: [TS playground](https://tsplay.dev/NavAPm). Alternative to `Record<K, Thing[K]>` is `Pick<Thing, K>`, depending on preference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) to add a property to an object and simultaneously narrow the apparent type of that object to match:

```
function addProp<T extends object, K extends PropertyKey, V>(
    obj: T,
    key: K,
    value: V
): asserts obj is T & { [P in K]: V } {
    Object.assign(obj, { [key]: value });
}
```

And we can can see it in action below:

```
const thing = {}
// const thing: {}
addProp(thing, "foo", string);
// const thing: {foo: string}
const knownToBeThing: Thing = thing; // works
```

Before the call to `addProp()`, the type of `thing` is just `{}`, while afterward the apparent type is equivalent to `Thing`.

---

Note that the call signature for `addProp()` is very general and allows you to add any property to any object:

```
addProp(thing, "random", 123);
// const thing: { foo: string; } & { random: number; }
```

If instead you want something targeted toward a particular type like `Thing` you can change the call signature to do so:

```
function addThingProp<K extends keyof Thing, P extends keyof Thing>(
    obj: { [Q in K]: Thing[Q] },
    key: P,
    value: Thing[P]
): asserts obj is { [Q in K | P]: Thing[Q] } {
    Object.assign(obj, { [key]: value });
}
```

which behaves similarly but warns on unexpected keys:

```
const thing = {};
// const thing: {}
addThingProp(thing, "foo", "abcde");
// const thing: {foo: string}
const knownToBeThing: Thing = thing; // okay

addThingProp(thing, "random", 123); // error!
// ---------------> ~~~~~~~~
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gcxBgyhjAJYrYBc8AFAJTwC8AfPJiWQNwCwAUKJLAmTosAWygAHSgFkJAHlalsAGngBXFAGsUSAO4pGPHhgCe4hABUAFoobwA3j3hP4AMyRJKCjjwC+XbobcLupgGMSo8FDAwAAKMEjisubwIAAeGCAowGjwSABGAFbgGCoA0inpmdnwcQkgMCalIMYqAGqMVI7O+QWU5kpdThrNlKUD3M7wAG5QEKoglK08NJRQaGj1GDk98MQ5yQBk9vAA2jG7KPClALqL8D72g-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-F6niGAAEJLXxABaUyzPMizjOYAA-Wy7NsnggA)

Comment: is there a way to do same thing for instance properties, *before* initializing instance? (so no use of `this`) like i define the class, than call addPropInstance(classdef), it adds the property to instance type.

Comment: I'd need to see a [mre] of what you're asking, and a comment on an old answer isn't really a great place to delve into such things. If you can't figure it out you might consider opening a new question post. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you explicitly *don't define* a variable type, Typescript can retype it as many times as nessesary

```
type Thing = {
    foo: string
    bar: number
}

const addProp = <T extends Partial<Thing>, K extends Exclude<keyof Thing, keyof T>>(
  obj: T,
  key: K,
  value: Thing[K]
): Pick<Thing, keyof Thing & (keyof T | K)> => Object.assign(obj, { [key]: value }) as any;

let thing; // should be on own line
thing = {}

thing = addProp(thing, 'foo', 'blank')
let unfinishedThing: Thing = thing;
//  ^! Property 'bar' is missing in type 'Pick<Thing, "foo">' but required in type 'Thing'.(2741)

thing = addProp(thing, 'bar', 123)
let finishedThing: Thing = thing;
// ok
```

It even has autocompletion for missing properties and value type hint

Comment: That first bit is what I was missing, thank you! I thought TypeScript might narrow it if it was inferred as `{}`, but apparently not. However, I tried it in a playground, and whether it works or not depends on `noImplicitAny` being enabled: if it is not, `thing` is never retyped ("Variable 'thing' implicitly has an 'any' type, but a better type may be inferred from usage. (7043)"), and the `addProp` function fails because `K` is `never` (because it is now based on `any`).