# Dynamically Generating Type for function return type

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-types, typescript-conditional-types

Here is my TypeScript code:

```js
type MetadataTags = {
  album: boolean;
  artist: boolean;
  genre: boolean;
  year: boolean;
  duration: boolean;
  contentType: boolean;
  artwork: boolean;
  directory: boolean;
};

type MusicScanResult<T extends MetadataTags> = {
  url: string;
  id: string;
  title: string;
} & (T['album'] extends true ? { album: string } : {}) & 
    (T['artist'] extends true ? { artist: string } : {}) &
    (T['genre'] extends true ? { genre: string } : {}) &
    (T['year'] extends true ? { year: string } : {}) &
    (T['duration'] extends true ? { duration: number } : {}) &
    (T['contentType'] extends true ? { contentType: string } : {}) &
    (T['artwork'] extends true ? { artwork: string } : {}) &
    (T['directory'] extends true ? { directory: string } : {});

function scanMediaStore<T extends MetadataTags>(metadata: T): MusicScanResult<T> {
  const map = new Map();
  map.set("url","sample");
  map.set("id","1233");
  map.set("title","adarsh");
  if(metadata.album) map.set("album","test");
  if(metadata.artist) map.set("artist","test");
  if(metadata.duration) map.set("duration",0);
  if(metadata.contentType) map.set("contentType","test");
  if(metadata.directory) map.set("directory","test");
  if(metadata.year) map.set("year","test");
  if(metadata.genre) map.set("genre","test");
  if(metadata.artwork) map.set("artwork","test");

  const res = Object.fromEntries(map);

  return res;
}
```

**Explanation**

The function will return an object which always contain

```js
{
  url: string;
  id: string;
  title: string;
}
```

Along with this, if any property of the metadata is true then the return value will also contain that property.

So I am trying to write a dynamic type definition for the function return type.
Note that the type of all the properties in the return type is `string`, except for property "duration", which is `number`.

**Problem**

When I directly pass the object to the function, the return type is generated correctly, including the properties that are marked as true in the metadata object. However, when I create a separate variable for the metadata object and pass that variable as the argument, I can only access the URL, ID, and title properties from the result. The other properties are not included in the type.

Calling the function:

```js
// This will work as expected.
const ans = scanMediaStore({
    album: true,
    artist: true,
    genre: false,
    year: false,
    duration: true,
    contentType: true,
    artwork: false,
    directory: false,
});
```

[image: Screenshot of TypeScript playground]

```
const metadata: MetadataTags = {
    album: true,
    artist: true,
    genre: false,
    year: false,
    duration: true,
    contentType: true,
    artwork: false,
    directory: false,
};

// This will not work as expected.
// Here I can only access url, id, title; the rest are not shown.
const ans = scanMediaStore(metadata);
```

[image: Screenshot of TypeScript playground]

Update: While I appreciate the solutions provided, I'm open to exploring different approaches to achieve the desired type in my code. If anyone has alternative solutions or suggestions to dynamically generate a TypeScript return type based on object properties, please feel free to share. I'm particularly interested in solutions that might offer better type inference or cleaner syntax.

Here is the [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6#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-i5wx55NtSPtNKQwQgoXCrtB0rZsrDEYEEV90xtb1iADMaFxQiYuFyMlw4KGEKkwooisCjbB4MhUAgMDhGkt+HQa3UEEw0MRXkwYEkUuksjk8oU0M0SGR+DqxFA6AgwC0uBBPLB50tXu452AAHTYeBLABE7QPABoD9gEHQwBwDxuW-Pd-uDwNTweAIwAJgAzF-b5uH3uwCHuMN5nrWAjYAAFn+-DCOmSytrUdbbls9DvFuj5AQeqF0K+dhiDBZBwQhbbIZCALoQBT7kQRZ74cAhFQMRiG1og25ymKXCUTugGHhxuangADHeRHwSx7bbua9iWhA3GYYeUm6jJeE5AxIlMWJpFsaGIRliAcm8QeOnhnpKkEepzFaQg24cgZT4cmZan9JpSFscSsmzlRWHuY5jGWa51mQs6vh2VhQXer5d5TqYM6KLgBAAPJUAAViZ27pgILB0AAorq3Q5Ah85RWQijAIYeZxbEUTEDV07ALOVktBO1zbEwYInvwNHiO6EAdWQ7lMOmlB7n1UAcoNw29fohjymYPWjYp+pWvNnVen4bXSqNxkJkm7WzFAsR1eQXC4C02AFkWwglmWEAkQFd5AA).

Comment: Please post the TypeScript playground links, instead of images.

Comment: provided the Typescript playground link

Comment: One thing you must keep in mind when you work with TypeScript: "always let TS infer the type". And TS lost all the credibility of doing that when you used `Object.fromEntries(map)`. You need to restructure the whole thing and use classes. For example, you can have `MusicScanResult` class (instead of type) which you can return from the `scanMediaStore` function. Then you don't have to explicitly declare the return type, as TS will be able to infer that automatically.

Comment: Re that part of the question, see also this [related question of mine about progressively adding properties to an object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76018978/15261914).

Comment: https://tsplay.dev/WKKKzW

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let's make sure `metadata`'s properties are not widened to just `boolean` and the object itself is type-safe, which can be achieved with the combination of the [satisfies](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html) and [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
// const metadata: {
//   readonly album: true;
//   readonly artist: true;
//   readonly genre: false;
//   readonly year: false;
//   readonly duration: true;
//   readonly contentType: true;
//   readonly artwork: true;
//   readonly directory: true;
// }
const metadata = {
  album: true,
  artist: true,
  genre: false,
  year: false,
  duration: true,
  contentType: true,
  artwork: true,
  directory: true,
} as const satisfies MetadataTags;
```

Now, let's create a type where the keys will be the keys of `MetadataTags` and the values will be what should function return if this property is true:

```
type TypeMap = {
  album: { album: string };
  artist: { artist: string };
  genre: { genre: string };
  year: { year: string };
  artwork: { artwork: string };
  duration: { duration: number };
  contentType: { contentType: string };
  directory: { directory: string };
};
```

Note that the values could be simplified to just `string` or `number` if you are sure that you won't add anything else:

```
type TypeMap = {
  album: string;
  artist: string;
  genre: string;
  year: string;
  artwork: string;
  duration: number;
  contentType: string;
  directory: string;
};
```

By using a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) and [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) we will drop the properties that are not true, otherwise, the values will be what's in the `TypeMap` for the specific property:

```
type Testing<T extends MetadataTags> = {
 [K in keyof TypeMap as T[K] extends true ? K : never]: TypeMap[K];
}
```

Testing:

Complex `TypeMap`:

```
//  type Result = {
//   album: {
//       album: string;
//   };
//   artist: {
//       artist: string;
//   };
//   artwork: {
//       artwork: string;
//   };
//   duration: {
//       duration: number;
//   };
//   contentType: {
//       contentType: string;
//   };
//   directory: {
//       directory: string;
//   };
// }
type Result = Testing<typeof metadata>
```

Simple `TypeMap`:

```
// type Result = {
//   album: string;
//   artist: string;
//   artwork: string;
//   duration: number;
//   contentType: string;
//   directory: string;
// }
type Result = Testing<typeof metadata>
```

With the simple version, the only thing left is to intersect the result with the rest of the return type, however in the complex version we have to take the values and make sure that they are *intersected*:

```
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (
  k: infer I,
) => void
  ? I
  : never;

type Testing<T extends MetadataTags> =  UnionToIntersection<ValueOf<{
  [K in keyof TypeMap as T[K] extends true ? K : never]: TypeMap[K];
 }>>
```

You can read more about the `ValueOf` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49285864/is-there-a-valueof-similar-to-keyof-in-typescript) and `UnionToIntersection` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type)

Testing:

```
// type Result = {
//   album: string;
// } & {
//   artist: string;
// } & {
//   year: string;
// } & {
//   duration: number;
// } & {
//   contentType: string;
// } & {
//   directory: string;
// } & {
//   artwork: string;
// }
type Result = Testing<typeof metadata>
```

To make the result type more readable the following utility type from the [type-samurai](https://github.com/KamilHs/type-samurai) can be used:

```
type Prettify<T> = T extends infer R
  ? {
      [K in keyof R]: R[K];
    }
  : never;
```

This type will remove intersections and will show them under a single object:

```
// type Result = {
//   album: string;
//   artist: string;
//   year: string;
//   artwork: string;
//   duration: number;
//   contentType: string;
//   directory: string;
// }
type Result = Testing<typeof metadata>
```

Looks good! Let's connect everything together:

```
type MusicScanResult<T extends MetadataTags> = Prettify<
  {
    url: string;
    id: string;
    title: string;
  } & UnionToIntersection<
    ValueOf<{
      [K in keyof TypeMap as T[K] extends true ? K : never]: TypeMap[K];
    }>
  >
>;
```

Final testing:

```
const metadata = {
  album: true,
  artist: true,
  genre: false,
  year: false,
  duration: true,
  contentType: true,
  artwork: true,
  directory: true,
} as const satisfies MetadataTags;

// const ans: {
//   url: string;
//   id: string;
//   title: string;
//   album: string;
//   artist: string;
//   artwork: string;
//   duration: number;
//   contentType: string;
//   directory: string;
// }
const ans = scanMediaStore(metadata);
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6&ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAshwEMAmDEBUEHMDOUC8UA3gFBRQIA2ARgK4C2AXFFQPYsUQIB2A3KeQCdgAS2zAmrdp179MELgIgS2HbnzIhOA5VLX8kNAamEsuO1TLIBjU8HnA04JcxXT1g4AHcWAgNbm3fWFFK2AfEAC9AF8+YlBIKEdIGAQwfCJ+SlpGInJqeiYxAWEuTCgYzKFRcVyEKrFC4GLS8vc5BWdCKHbFRuayio0tJi7NOr6Sgfc6rx9-WqFvPwmWwagDIxFTEfXDY22oLnoqCAFW-hsuOyukzqhL64cnFamgkLCBCNykYIhQ8Je5wqcScUAAapQaBAAPIAMwAPGgAHzpNAAbV8EBALFhiQAunx4tAAKpcExcNAsACSV1O2D+Wy48OJKIIAApiVAIAAPa5IXDcEBQAD8UDZ82JAEp8CiAG4sYRIKBMLgQWWnaU8vm4Nn8eYlWGnKBUgA0xGleDlCqQ-FFVP4KrVp1iRKgAAVFMARLCQIjWYkubz5PyoAajQAlW0ZMgxqBogDSoa4UEx2Nx4bxTHDCYJ-DIUQdhydAhdoJgNGwwisAGUrNxwxBsDQKMBEYHtbB4MhUAgMDh-R74N7ffwSLHDBQXu4yIqp3moCJgBw5-moAAyKCk8mUml2AT00Lk+HziEUKFw+Fj2NxxMlFNYnGJJwpNIIXDo+N49vB3BNKEiqBE0ddUBEzJ9klSHNp3KJF+FgpFYlhGguEPUwoGwOsuDgH4EGrD4IDbLUf07RAUHQLBsCRXUyDoLsyIQJg0DNSUmHLSsa0whsmxbP1o3uUwxCgOhUnSVVPFgVI2UldxhLAAA6elgDZAByCdlJNKBlOwBA6DADhlOk-hZIU+AVMVdTNIARgAJgAZlsgyZNSEylOUxd9I05Tu33AALRz+GEXE2Vo0iezkrJ6GlYzFJUiK6AstzG2AfyZyCkLu0QcL6mAKLnJirzsoSuwxBS0M0rosKNn2Lhcvk-KqsZCyAAZDNSsV0vouSHnsW5apclTupuJwiqS0rAvairMp+d5wj6+rfn+T4RpK1qyom0LMrGAQ5tM5StuW5LVvG4LJoQOSeggHbXIug6xvKjazpmJZfCu2LFjmW7DIuATgCgRRcAIaEqAAKwZOTYQEFg6AAUSuYpG2C1IvrIT1DGTf6+ALYhLkEjqe3SK84qYP8IDNMgZmqYmBChMnunkXooFhSh6VpramCZigWf0PZGSpmnvtpIbID50nKlmZYF2p0WyGmhkAUl-monIXAcd+7SRGwWFhEbEiMt7CjYgAekN-iuEE7hsBGYhjZjCc5xtmckHtk2yHc5wikmPgHbybJnZjCmGnQppPetl2PGev2ZZ58kVWOZ1Q5jQanmFoP+i9sPZcWr4PdKdPymxn7yDN9IMO4bDhFw-CToewygA)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are annotating `metadata` as `MetadataTags`, it is widened to that type. Because of this, all the properties of `metadata` or of type `boolean`, instead of `true` or `false`.

Instead of the annotation, you should use `satisfies` to make sure it satisfies the required type without widening the actual used type.

```js
const metadata = {
    album: true,
    artist: true,
    genre: false,
    year: false,
    duration: true,
    contentType: true,
    artwork: false,
    directory: false,
} satisfies MetadataTags;

const ans = scanMediaStore(metadata);
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6#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-i5wx55NtSPtNKQwQgoXCrtB0rZsrDEYEEV90xtb1iADMaFxQiYuFyMlw4KGEKkwooisCjbB4MhUAgMDhGkt+HQa3UEEw0MRXkwYEkUuksjk8oU0M0SGR+DqxFA6AgwC0uBBPLB50tXu452AAHTYeBLABE7QPABoD9gEHQwBwDxuW-Pd-uDwNTweAIwAJgAzF-b5uH3uwCHuMN5nrWAjYAAFn+-DCOmSytrUdbbls9DvFuj5AQeqF0K+dhiDBZBwQhbbIZCALoQBT7kQRZ74cAhFQMRiG1og25ymKXCUTugGHhxuangADHeRHwSx7bbua9iWhA3GYYeUm6jJeE5AxIlMWJpFsaGIRliAcm8QeOnhnpKkEepzFaQg24cgZT4cmZan9JpSFscSsmzlRWHuY5jGWa51mQs6vh2VhQXer5d5TqYM6KLgBAAPJUAAViZ27pgILB0AAorq3Q5Ah85RWQijAIYeZxXwUTEMQ07ALOVktBO1zbEwYInvwNHiO6EAdWQ7lMOmlB7n1UAcoNw29fohjymYPWjYp+pWvNnVen4bXSqNxkJkm7WzFyxjYOmwg5NWAUNtgsR1eQXDxfm3BFsIJZlhAJEBXeAD0H32gAeucxBAA)

Comment: Please can you provide any different way of writing the dynamic (conditional) type

Comment: Is that part of this question? If not, please ask a new, separate question.

Comment: I can, though, if you do post a new question. But on Monday. I'm on my phone, and was actually just browsing.

Comment: is there is any other approach to write the type for this code?

Comment: Yes, but that is outside the scope of this question. You asked why the return type wasn't what was expected, not about alternative ways to write one of the types.

Comment: okay i have edited my question, please can you provide any alternative ways ;)